# How to retrieve data from PUT,DELETE method golang (gin gonic)

Tags: go, put

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",(or "DELETE")
        url: "example.com/controller",
        data: {
            ID: 10,
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {}

    });
```

here my ajax, and in my controller i want to get ID, but c.PostForm("ID") not work for delete(work for PUT), help me please!

Finally, i have to pass params to URI.(delete method)

Comment: Where is your go code ?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/tOFxziLgGo example here, thanks for reply

Comment: You can find the answer from [If a DELETE request includes an entity body, the body is ignored [...]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to call the ParseForm method first - https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm

Comment: test := c.Request.ParseForm()  not work for me, i return nil

Comment: Try accessing the postform params after calling the ParseForm function. I don't use gin myself but that is how the http package works iirc